# Vue dynamic array computed from data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Say I have this data retrieved from my store:

```js
let itemsData=[
  {id:1,data:[...]},
  {id:2,data:[...]},
  {id:3,data:[...]}
]
```

I need to be able to produce an array from this data which looks something like this:

```js
let itemsSelected=[
  {id:1,selected:false},
  {id:2,selected:false},
  {id:3,selected:false}
]
```

And then I need to have this array, `itemsSelected`, accessible to determine the state of multiple different components in the template, for example:

```html
<div v-for="item in itemsSelected" :key="item.id" :class="item.selected?'selected':''"></div>
```

I originally thought to use a computed property, but **I need to be able to dynamically update the `selected` value of items in itemsSelected**. However, I also want the array to be constructed based on data in the store, and **it should add/remove items from `itemsSelected` whenever `itemsData` changes**. How can I achieve these things together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watcheffect) to update `itemSelected` based on `itemsData`. The following example uses [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create a new map of item IDs to a shallow copy of the original array item *plus* a `selected` property:

```js
import { watchEffect, ref, reactive } from 'vue'

let itemsData = reactive([
  { id: 1, data: [newData()] },
  { id: 2, data: [newData()] },
  { id: 3, data: [newData()] },
])

let itemsSelected = ref({})

watchEffect(() => {
  const selections = itemsSelected.value
  itemsSelected.value = itemsData.reduce((p, c) => {
    p[c.id] = {
      ...c,
      selected: selections[c.id]?.selected ?? false,
    }
    return p
  }, {})
})
```

This allows `itemsSelected` to still be editable, enabling modification of the `selected` properties in `itemsSelected` without affecting `itemsData`.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-track-prop-selections?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FItemList.vue)

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering why you're having itemsSelected return as an ID-indexed object rather than as an array? I know an object might work just as well in the example I gave, but in the actual use case there are places where an array is more convenient. Is the problem that it would be very performance intensive to search an array for each ID in itemsData?

Comment: The map makes for a simpler lookup in this simplified example. A lookup (*O(1)*) vs an array scan (*O(n)*) has a significant performance difference, but it might be negligible for small arrays (<1K). Do what works best (not necessarily for performance) for your use case. Out of curiosity, what are some examples of your use case where an array is more convenient?